# Adapting existing ng-container tree into virtual tree

Tags: angular, angular7, angular-cdk-virtual-scroll

I have a very, very bare minimal tree, that sometimes needs to render thousands upon thousands of elements. This results in some very poor performance, so the site gets quite laggy. I instead opted to try out `cdk-virtual-scroll-viewport`, but I cannot get it to work, because I'm using `ngTemplateOutlet`. Example:

```
<ul>
    <ng-template #recursiveList let-root>
        <li *ngFor="let item of root; trackBy:item?.id">

            <!-- Show the actual elements, including + and - to expand/contract the tree -->

            <ul [ngClass]="item?.expanded ? '' : 'hide'" *ngIf="item?.children && item?.children.length > 0">
                <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="recursiveList; context:{ $implicit: item?.children }"></ng-container>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ng-template>
    <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="recursiveList; context:{ $implicit: root }"></ng-container>
</ul>
```

My `root` array looks a bit like this:

```
[{
  id: "aec04ef4-fc6a-481f-a12d-0ce987d494b3",
  expanded: true,
  children: [{
    id: "cbf9e862-e932-410f-ad84-ed0a5ec1917a",
    expanded: false,
    children: []
  }]
}]
```

I tried simply doing this:

```
<ul>
    <ng-template #recursiveList let-root>
        <li *cdkVirtualFor="let item of root; trackBy:item?.id">

            <!-- Show the actual elements, including + and - to expand/contract the tree -->

            <ul [ngClass]="item?.expanded ? '' : 'hide'" *ngIf="item?.children && item?.children.length > 0">
                <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="recursiveList; context:{ $implicit: item?.children }"></ng-container>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ng-template>

    <cdk-virtual-scroll-viewport style="height: 750px" itemSize="50">
        <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="recursiveList; context:{ $implicit: root }"></ng-container>
    </cdk-virtual-scroll-viewport>
</ul>
```

So basically added the `cdk-virtual-scroll-viewport` element and used `cdkVirtualFor` instead of `ngFor`, but I get an error saying:

> No provider for CdkVirtualScrollViewport

Which I guess is a bug, since it hasn't been closed: https://github.com/angular/components/issues/15277

Any idea how to adapt my existing code? The biggest problem I face, is the hide/unhide part, because it uses `ng-container` that for some reason won't work.

Answer (score 0):

After trying various CDK virtualization methods and never getting satisfactory results, I built a custom component for this.

https://github.com/gjcampbell/ooffice/tree/master/projects/of-tree

I recommend using a library (mine has the best performance I know of), or if you'd rather stick to your current path, then do this:

1. On your data, store hierarchy info such as each item's depth and parent
2. Recurse through the data and create a flat list from the hierarchical data
3. Render the flat list without recursive templates. Use the depth to determine indentation. Pass to `cdkVirtualFor` only items whose parent is null or expanded.